# Docker-compose: how to know when jar inside a container finish to run and later start other container

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose

I have multiple containers and I run differents jars inside of each one, but one of those jar need to run after one jar finish to start, so I used the `depends_on` property of my docker-compose.yml but this only works when the container finished,  not the jar, so how can I tell to one container to wait until the jar inside of another container end to start,

This is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  cloudconfig:
    image: cloudconfig
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
    hostname: cloudconfig
    container_name: cloudconfig
  eureka1:
    image: eureka
    ports:
      - "8011:8011"
    hostname: eureka-primary
    container_name: eureka-primary
    environment:
      - perfil=-Dspring.profiles.active=primary
  eureka2:
    image: eureka
    hostname: eureka-secondary
    container_name: eureka-secondary
    environment:
      - perfil=-Dspring.profiles.active=secondary
  eureka3:
    image: eureka
    hostname: eureka-tertiary
    container_name: eureka-tertiary
    environment:
      - perfil=-Dspring.profiles.active=tertiary
  mscargos:
    depends_on: 
      - "eureka1"
      - "eureka2"
      - "eureka3"
    image: mscargos
    hostname: mscargos
    container_name: mscargos
  zuul:
    depends_on:
      - "mscargos"
    image: zuul
    ports:
      - "8125:8125"
    hostname: zuul
    container_name: zuul
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no clean way of doing that, there are only workarounds.

**Official [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) says** that you have to use external tools, like `./wait-for-it.sh`.

> Use a tool such as wait-for-it, dockerize or sh-compatible wait-for.
>   These are small wrapper scripts which you can include in your
>   application’s image and will poll a given host and port until it’s
>   accepting TCP connections.

What you have to do is implement some REST endpoint that will return HTTP 200 once container is ready. The dependent container must be hitting this endpoint untill it gets HTTP 200 and only then start the main process.

You can use something like this:

Dockerfile:

```
ADD wait-for-it.sh /wait-for-it.sh
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
command: bash -c "./wait-for-it.sh your-servise:8080 && java -jar your-app.jar"
```

**There is also more simple and strait forward way**, that does not require implementation of any APIs. You can simply add some sleep command right before the process that requires the others to be alive.

In that way your compose might look like this:

```
command: bash -c "sleep 60s && java -jar your-app.jar"
```

However you should investigate if this approach is suitable in your case.

**Note:** I used `java -jar your-app.jar` as an example but you might have some different command (even not java). Just replace this part with the way you start your process.